# Run Javascript between two Divs

Tags: javascript, php, html, popup

I want to run javascript code (pop-up ads) between two div.

I want pop-up ads run just in a part of my page (content) and not run in header and footer.

my pop-up script is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">var zarpop_user_id = 4518;var zarpop_userMax = 3;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://zarpop.com/website/js" async></script>
```

how to put this code in my website ?

my index code is :

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="center">

<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sky-centerblock.php'); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : $themeu = get_bloginfo('template_url'); ?>

<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post();?>

<div class="post">

<div class="inside"><?php the_content(''); ?>

<br /><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="readmore"></a>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="morebt"></a>

</div>

<div class="pagenumbers">


<? if (function_exists('wp_corenavi')) wp_corenavi(); ?></div>

</div>
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sky-leftblock.php'); ?>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the browser won't notice any difference, you can put the script where you want (the first one just sets some global variables; the second will start doing something only when the browser finishes downloading it; this should be the meaning of async).

So.. just be careful to place them outside php tags (outside php opening and closing tags), so that php won't parse that part: it will just put your script tags in the html, "as is", in the position where you would expect it.

Note that the js code will run anyway inside the browser (window), rather than in header/middle/footer of html